# How to stop project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, project

How to stop a running project?
The way like in `NetBeans -> terminate project`.

Comment: Take a deep breath, and click the stop button, it's a red square. You'd see it on the top of the Console view, amongst others. "it is not intuitive AT ALL" is a very subjective opinion, give the popularity of Eclipse as a Java IDE

Comment: OHH MY FREE FISH IN THE OCEAN, how I envy you , just swim and eat.. The default eclipse package I've downloaded had no console window by default view - that's a good start.  IF IT IS SO GOOD WHY ORACLE SUPPORTS NETBEANS , NOT ECLIPSE :/

Comment: It is not what Oracle supports that defines what is good or not. What IDE is better than another is a matter of personal choice and taste. Eclipse proved itself through it's popularity. If you need help using it there is no need to shout.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but for the record Oracle supports a number of IDEs as we do not want to dictate to the user what tools they should be using. Oracle is the second largest contributor to Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

Note, there is no need to yell. Those of us who started in Eclipse could say the same about netbeans.

The button you are looking for is part of the *Console*. This is represented by a small blue computer screen. It can typically be found somewhere along the bottom of your screen.

If you can't find the console, go to Window > Show View > Console.

Then you will see a red stop button as part of the console. This will terminate the running program, leaving the console messages behind. Then you can press the black X to clear the console. Or the double X to clear all terminated consoles.

Comment: Thanks thanks, sorry guys, but I imagine you understand what I feel when you can't do operation which you've done 1k times before...

Comment: It happens to the best of us. I think I've just invented a word for it: `code rage`

Comment: Also, the console _is_ part of the default Java view. Though you never mentioned what language you were using...

Comment: Peaches491, the 'Remove All Terminated Launches" button is greyed out for me. I have a large number of programs sitting in the console, but I only seem to be able to individually terminate each process... any ideas?

Comment: My console doesn't have a stop button.  What do?